# Windows 10 minimalist file explorer icon

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, icons, start-menu

I've only have Win10 for a couple days, but I've noticed something odd. Almost all of the system apps I can pin to the taskbar have these cool, white, minimalist icons, but file explorer is still the same manila folder. I know this icon exists because when I go to Start Settings -> Choose Folders and turn on File Explorer, the icon on the left of the start menu is a lovely minimalist icon. Is there a way to change the file explorer icon just for the taskbar, so it matches the others? Thanks